# Change default button upon press in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have two buttons in a wrap panel in WPF and one of them has `IsDefault="True"`. When I click on the other, I want it to become the "default button".

I realize I can do this programmatically by listening to the press event, but I want a universal solution that does not require me to wire up a lot of code here and there.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to implement it in a more declarative session, you could define a WPF `EventTrigger` over the Clicked event of the Button and define a Storyboard that changes the `IsDefault` properties of affected buttons.

Here is the sample that demonstrates what I mean:

```
<Window x:Class="TriggerSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">   
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="one" Content="One">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard >
                                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.IsEnabled)">
                                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" />
                                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="Two" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

It changes the IsEnabled property so you can test that it works. Then you can change it to the IsDefault property (which will obviously get the value True)

Comment: The way I see, the idea here is to make `IsEnabled` to `false` for any button that is clicked? Isn't there any concept of "button group" in WPF that you can just wrap buttons inside a container and then there's code that listens on clicks on any buttons inside the button group and then handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `InvertBooleanConverter` and bind the `IsDefault` property of the first button to the inverse on the second button, then you just have to set `IsDefault` to off using triggers on the first button and the second button would switch automatically to on!

```xml
<Button x:Name="B1" IsDefault="True"/>
<Button x:Name="B2" IsDefault="{Binding ElementName=B1, IsDefault, Converter={StaticResource InvertBooleanConverter}}"/>
```

If you use "Jan Kratochvil" Style Triggers from his answer with my Bindings this should work easy in full-XAML.

Comment: I'm afraid not! As a boolean has only 2 states ;)